# Can I learn SAS online?

Tags: sas, careers, internet

I'll complete my Master's degree in a year and I was thinking of learning SAS as I've heard it gives you an edge over other candidates while being recruited. Could you tell me if I can learn it online and learn it well?

Comment: Part of this is addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89376/do-i-have-to-learn-sas-if-i-want-to-go-into-industry and indeed elsewhere here. It's difficult to summarize impartially, but note that many people challenge the alleged importance or dominance of SAS, with a mix of reasons varying from disliking it on principle to emphasising the usefulness and widespread use of other software in practice.

Comment: From my experience (hiring & being hired) it doesn't matter all that much which particular languages candidates for statistician posts have learnt, as long as they've practice in statistical programming. As a graduate there may be more distinctive strings you could add to your bow than one more technical competency - volunteering to work in your university's stats clinic, off the top of my head. Of course things vary a lot between industries & countries, so don't take that as gospel; but equally, don't believe everything you hear.

Answer (score 5):

**Online resources:**

[UCLA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/) has compiled a list of resources

You can also use Google search term such as `SAS learning filetype:pdf` to look for tutorials. For instance, I found this [great list](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2003/TD02-Stojanovic.pdf) made by Stojanovic.

SAS User Group International (SUGI) also posts [conference proceedings online](http://support.sas.com/events/sasglobalforum/previous/online.html). Each paper addresses a particular topic in various degree of complexity. Most of them are structured as a mini tutorial, which is user friendly. (Tip: the site requires a search term, if you're not sure, just leave it empty and click the search button.)

SAS also put a lot of manuals online. For instance, if you Google search `proc reg filetype:pdf`, you'll find the manual hosted at support.sas.com. You can get a good understanding on handy procedures such as `proc sql` and `ods` (Output Delivery System) this way.

**Book:**

Even online resources are everywhere, there are a couple SAS books that I still read all the time. First, if money allows, I'd suggest get a few titles by [Cody](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Ron+Cody). Among which, I'd suggest strongly [Learning SAS by Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1599941651) (Here is an [excerpt](http://www.sas.com/storefront/aux/en/splearnexample/60864_excerpt.pdf)), [Applied Statistics and the SAS Programming Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131465325), and perhaps [Cody's Data Cleaning Techniques Using SAS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1599946599), but this last one is not essential at the early stage.

Another classic you should check out is the [The Little SAS Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1612903436). It covers a lot of basics, and I'd recommend paring this with Learning SAS by Example; that way you should be able to tackle most of the basic stuff.